# Json deserializ issue

Tags: json

i have a json in this format . how to deserializ.

[{"simCardID":"0c00ddc0-f47d-e011-8f18-0019995cafa5","virtualNumbers":[{"CountryID":"2","Area_Code":"260","Period":"6","TableRowIndex":0}]},{"simCardID":"ed283768-9be1-e111-9118-782bcb0d9de4","virtualNumbers":[]},{"simCardID":"8b576960-bf9d-e111-9118-782bcb0d9de4","virtualNumbers":[]}]

thanks in advance

Comment: deserialize into 
c# language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a language-agnostic string format for representing data objects or relationships. It's unclear from the question, as currently posted, what you're trying to deserialize your JSON string into.

Your language probably has a very simple parse function. If you're using JavaScript, for example, you would simply call `JSON.parse`.

```
my_json_string = '[{"simCardID":"0c00ddc0-f47d-e011-8f18-0019995cafa5"}]' // snipped

JSON.parse(my_json_string) // => [{ simCardID: '0c00ddc0-f47d-e011-8f18-0019995cafa5' }]
```